# How do I subscribe to asynchronous response from getMedia?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress-gutenberg

I Have an image saved in the attributes of a Gutenberg block and what I'd like to do is, when block is mounted / rendered, check to see if that image has been removed from the media library, and if so, remove it from the block attributes.

What I have so far looks like this:

```
const checkSavedImage = ({id},update)=>{
    const media =  useSelect( ( select ) => {
        return select('core').getMedia(id);
    }, [] );
    useEffect(() => {
            update(media);
    }, [media])
}

export default ( {attributes,setAttributes} ) => {

    const { imageMobile } = attributes;

    checkSavedImage(imageMobile,(image)=>setAttributes({imageMobile:image ? {id:image.id,url:image.source_url} : {}}));


    return (
            <Image
            onRemove={()=>setAttributes({imageMobile:{}})}
            onSelect={image=>setAttributes({imageMobile:{id:image.id,url:image.url}})}
            image={imageMobile}     
            />)
}
```

This does work but the initial response from `select('core').getMedia(id)` comes back with `undefined` and then later comes back with the media object when the request is resolved. This results in an update to the block attributes, first removing the image, then re-inserting it which prompts the user to save their changes before navigating away from the page even when they made none.

Ultimately what I'm struggling with is the fact that `select('core').getMedia(id)` returns `undefined` both when it is still resolving OR if the media item was deleted.

I think that the correct method is to leverage `subscribe` or `isResolving` but I can not find any examples to help with this specific use case.

I'm looking for help to update the block attributes with an empty object when, and only when, the image was removed from the media library